# how to deserialize a json string that contains @@ with scala'

Tags: json, scala, gson

As the title already explains, I would like to deserialize a json string that contains a key that starts with @@. With the @@ my standard approach using case classes sadly does not work anymore.

```scala
val test = """{"@@key": "value"}"""
case class Test(@@key: String) // not possible
val gson =  new GsonBuilder().create()
val res = gson.fromJson(test, classOf[Test])
```

How can work with the @@ withtout preprocessing the input json string?

Comment: There are at least five great Scala json libraries. Why use one fork Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer is to quote the field name:

```
case class Test(`@@key`: String)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This deserializes the posted example to Test(null)..

Comment: Maybe GSON does not understand this. It should work with Scala JSON libraries.

Comment: Come to think of it, since the JVM-bytecode-level field name will not be `@@key` but encoded in some way to be compatible with the naming rules there, a Java-reflection based library that is not Scala-aware most certainly will not be able to match the names.

Comment: (This is still the best answer, though, you "just" need to switch to a Scala-based JSON library :-) )

Answer (score 2):

I experimented a bit but it seems that GSON doesn't interoperate well with Scala `case class`es (or the other way around, I guess it's a matter of perspective). I tried playing around with `scala.beans.BeanProperty` but it doesn't seem like it makes a difference.

A possible way to go is to use a regular `class` and the `SerializedName` annotation, as in this example:

```
import com.google.gson.{FieldNamingPolicy, GsonBuilder}
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

final class Test(k: String) {
  @SerializedName("@@key") val key = k
  override def toString(): String = s"Test($key)"
}

val test = """{"@@key": "foobar"}"""
val gson =  new GsonBuilder().create()
val res = gson.fromJson(test, classOf[Test])
println(res)
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie.](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/njnkvxtIQw6GTwzCMnTvGg/30)

You can read more on `SerializedName` (as well as other naming-related GSON features) [here on the user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#json-field-naming-support).

Comment: I'm not sure of _why_ it doesn't work with `case class`es though. Having a look with `javap` it looks that from a public interface standpoint, the `case class` is a strict superset of the normal class. It appears that the `case class` rather has something additional that ends up preventing GSON from doing it's job. Not sure though, just speculating.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Scala programmer, I just used `javap` and reflection to check what the Scala compiler generated and slightly "learnt" how some Scala internals work.
It does not work for you because of several reasons:

- The Scala compiler puts case class elements annotations to the constructor parameters, whereas Gson `@SerializedName` can only work with [fields and methods](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/ceae88bd6667f4263bbe02e6b3710b8a683906a2/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.java#L82):

```scala
// does not work as expected
case class Test(@SerializedName("@@key") `@@key`: String)
```

From the plain Java perspective:

```java
final Constructor<Test> constructor = Test.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);
System.out.println(constructor);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(constructor.getParameterAnnotations()));
```

> `public Test(java.lang.String)`
>   `[[@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName(alternate=[], value=@@key)]]`

Not sure why the Scala compiler does not replicate the annotations directly to the fields, but the Java language does not allow annotating parameters with the `@SerializedName` annotation causing a compilation error (JVM does not treats it as a failure either).

- The field name is actually encoded in the class file.

From the Java perspective:

```java
final Field field = Test.class.getDeclaredField("$at$atkey"); // the real name of the `@@key` element
System.out.println(field);
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(field.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
```

> `private final java.lang.String Test.$at$atkey` <- this is how the field can be accessed from Java
>   `[]` <- no annotations by default

- Scala allows moving annotations to fields and this would make your code work accordingly to how Gson `@SerializedName` is designed (of course, no Scala in mind):

```scala
import scala.annotation.meta.field
...
case class Test(@(SerializedName@field)("@@key") `@@key`: String)
```

> `Test(value)`

---

If for some/any reason you must use Gson and can't annotate each field with `@SerializedName`, then you can implement a custom type adapter, but I'm afraid that you have to have deep knowledge in how Scala works.
If I understand what Scala does, it annotates every generated class with the `@ScalaSignature` annotation.
The annotation provides the `bytes()` method that returns a payload that's most likely can be used to detect whether the annotated type is a case class, and probably how its members are declared.
I didn't find such a parser/decoder, but if you find one, you can do the following in Gson:

- register a type adapter factory that checks whether it can handle it (basically, analyzing the `@ScalaSignature` annotation, I believe);
- if it can, then create a type adapter that is aware of all case class fields, their names possibly handling the `@SerializedName` yourself, as you can neither extend Gson `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` nor inject a name remapping strategy;
- take `transient` fields (for good) and other exclusion strategies (for completeness) into account;
- read/write each non-excluded field.

Too much work, right? So I see two easy options here: either use a Scala-aware JSON tool like other people are suggesting, or annotate each field that have such a special name.