# Gson with Scala causes StackOverflow for Enumerations

Tags: scala, gson, stack-overflow

I have an enum defined in Scala class as follows

```
// define compression types as enumerator
  object CompressionType extends Enumeration
  {
    type CompressionType = Value
    
    val None, Gzip, Snappy, Lz4, Zstd = Value    
  }
```

and I have class that I want to Serialize in JSON

```
case class ProducerConfig(batchNumMessages : Int, lingerMs : Int, messageSize : Int,
                            topic: String, compressionType: CompressionType.Value )
```

That class includes the Enum object. It seems that using GSON to serialize causes StackOverflow due to some circular dependency.

```
val gson = new Gson
      val jsonBody = gson.toJson(producerConfig)
      println(jsonBody)
```

Here is the stack trace I get below. I saw this [question here and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31341048/gsonjava-lang-stackoverflowerror-null/52051976#52051976) except the solution seems to be Java solution and didn't work for scala. Can someone clarify?

```
17:10:04.475 [ERROR] i.g.a.Gatling$ - Run crashed
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.beforeName(JsonWriter.java:617)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:400)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:526)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:233)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.write(TypeAdapters.java:218)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a Scala guy but I think Gson is a wrong tool to use here.

- Firstly, Gson is not aware of `scala.Enumeration` therefore handling it as a regular data bag that's traversable using reflection.
- Secondly, there is no an easy (if any?) way of deserializing to the original value state (can be ignored if you're going only to produce, not consume, JSON documents).

Here is why:

```scala
object Single
        extends Enumeration {

    val Only = Value

}
```

```java
final class Internals {

    private Internals() {
    }

    static void inspect(final Object o, final Excluder excluder, final boolean serialize)
            throws IllegalAccessException {
        inspect(o, clazz -> !excluder.excludeClass(clazz, serialize), field -> !excluder.excludeField(field, serialize));
    }

    static void inspect(final Object o, final Predicate<? super Class<?>> inspectClass, final Predicate<? super Field> inspectField)
            throws IllegalAccessException {
        for ( Class<?> c = o.getClass(); c != null; c = c.getSuperclass() ) {
            if ( !inspectClass.test(c) ) {
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println(c);
            for ( final Field f : c.getDeclaredFields() ) {
                if ( !inspectField.test(f) ) {
                    continue;
                }
                f.setAccessible(true);
                System.out.printf("\t%s: %s\n", f, f.get(o));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```java
final Object value = Single.Only();
Internals.inspect(value, gson.excluder(), true);
```

produces:

```
class scala.Enumeration$Val
    private final int scala.Enumeration$Val.i: 0
    private final java.lang.String scala.Enumeration$Val.name: null
class scala.Enumeration$Value
    private final scala.Enumeration scala.Enumeration$Value.scala$Enumeration$$outerEnum: Single
class java.lang.Object
```

As you can see, there are two crucial fields:

- `private final java.lang.String scala.Enumeration$Val.name` gives null unless named (the enumeration element can be obtained using `toString` though).
- `private final scala.Enumeration scala.Enumeration$Value.scala$Enumeration$$outerEnum` is actually a reference to the concrete enumeration outer class (that's actually the cause of the infinite recursion and hence stack overflow error).

These two prevent from proper deserialization.
The outer enum type can be obtained in at least three ways:

- either implement custom type adapters for *all* types that can contain such enumerations (pretty easy for data bags (case classes in Scala?) as fields already contain the type information despite Gson provides poor support of this; won't work for single primitive literals like the above or collections);
- or bake the outer enumeration name to JSON holding two entries for the name and outer type.

The latter could be done like this (in Java, hope it's easy to simplify it in Scala):

```java
final class ScalaStuff {

    private static final Field outerEnumField;
    private static final Map<String, Method> withNameMethodCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    static {
        try {
            outerEnumField = Enumeration.Value.class.getDeclaredField("scala$Enumeration$$outerEnum");
            outerEnumField.setAccessible(true);
        } catch ( final NoSuchFieldException ex ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private ScalaStuff() {
    }

    @Nonnull
    static String toEnumerationName(@Nonnull final Enumeration.Value value) {
        try {
            final Class<? extends Enumeration> aClass = ((Enumeration) outerEnumField.get(value)).getClass();
            final String typeName = aClass.getTypeName();
            final int length = typeName.length();
            assert !typeName.isEmpty() && typeName.charAt(length - 1) == '$';
            return typeName.substring(0, length - 1);
        } catch ( final IllegalAccessException ex ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Nonnull
    static Enumeration.Value fromEnumerationValue(@Nonnull final String type, @Nonnull final String enumerationName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {
        // using get for exception propagation cleanliness; computeIfAbsent would complicate exception handling
        @Nullable
        final Method withNameMethodCandidate = withNameMethodCache.get(type);
        final Method withNameMethod;
        if ( withNameMethodCandidate != null ) {
            withNameMethod = withNameMethodCandidate;
        } else {
            final Class<?> enumerationClass = Class.forName(type);
            withNameMethod = enumerationClass.getMethod("withName", String.class);
            withNameMethodCache.put(type, withNameMethod);
        }
        try {
            return (Enumeration.Value) withNameMethod.invoke(null, enumerationName);
        } catch ( final IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException ex ) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

```java
final class ScalaEnumerationTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory instance = new ScalaEnumerationTypeAdapterFactory();

    private ScalaEnumerationTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    static TypeAdapterFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( !Enumeration.Value.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            return null;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) Adapter.instance;
        return typeAdapter;
    }

    private static final class Adapter
            extends TypeAdapter<Enumeration.Value> {

        private static final TypeAdapter<Enumeration.Value> instance = new Adapter()
                .nullSafe();

        private Adapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Enumeration.Value value)
                throws IOException {
            out.beginObject();
            out.name("type");
            out.value(ScalaStuff.toEnumerationName(value));
            out.name("name");
            out.value(value.toString());
            out.endObject();
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration.Value read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            in.beginObject();
            @Nullable
            String type = null;
            @Nullable
            String name = null;
            while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                switch ( in.nextName() ) {
                case "type":
                    type = in.nextString();
                    break;
                case "name":
                    name = in.nextString();
                    break;
                default:
                    in.skipValue();
                    break;
                }
            }
            in.endObject();
            if ( type == null || name == null ) {
                throw new JsonParseException("Insufficient enum data: " + type + ", " + name);
            }
            try {
                return ScalaStuff.fromEnumerationValue(type, name);
            } catch ( final ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException ex ) {
                throw new JsonParseException(ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The following JUnit 5 test will passed:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .disableHtmlEscaping()
        .registerTypeAdapterFactory(ScalaEnumerationTypeAdapterFactory.getInstance())
        .create();

@Test
public void test() {
    final Enumeration.Value before = Single.Only();
    final String json = gson.toJson(before);
    System.out.println(json);
    final Enumeration.Value after = gson.fromJson(json, Enumeration.Value.class);
    Assertions.assertSame(before, after);
}
```

where the `json` variable would hold the following JSON payload:

```
{"type":"Single","name":"Only"}
```

The `ScalaStuff` class above is most likely not complete. See more at [how to deserialize a json string that contains @@ with scala'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259410/how-to-deserialize-a-json-string-that-contains-with-scala) for Scala and Gson implications.

---

Update 1

Since you don't need to consume the produced JSON documents assuming the JSON consumers can deal with the enumeration deserialization themselves, you can produce an enumeration value name that's more descriptive than producing nameless ints. Just replace the `Adapter` above:

```java
private static final class Adapter
        extends TypeAdapter<Enumeration.Value> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<Enumeration.Value> instance = new Adapter()
            .nullSafe();

    private Adapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Enumeration.Value value)
            throws IOException {
        out.value(value.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration.Value read(final JsonReader in) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

}
```

Then following test will be green:

```java
Assertions.assertEquals("\"Only\"", gson.toJson(Single.Only()));
```

Comment: wow thanks so much. I didn't realize how bad Gson is with Scala Enumerators. To unblock myself I removed the enumerator and just have integer value instead. I am only producing JSON and not de-serializing.

Comment: @SaherAhwal Well, Gson is just not designed for use with Scala as it still supports Java "native" enums out of box really well. If you don't need to deserialize the generated enums, and probably don't need to retain the type information, please see the answer update.